# Opening drop down menus

Tags: browser

I have 4 browsers on a Linux system.

One of them, a firefox-esr browser, opens drop down menus okay.

The other three - Chrome (version 65), Chromium (version 57) and Opera (version 45) - cannot open drop down menus. The latter three are based on Chrome.

I suspect that the Chrome type browsers use code different from Firefox type browsers for opening drop down menus.

Can anyone help, please ?

Is the problem connected with Javascript ?

Comment: Could you show a screenshot of one page where it doesn't work and a link to the web-page?

Comment: I should have been clearer in my question. I cannot open drop down menus in the browsers themselves. The question is : are drop down menus in Google browsers coded differently from those un Firefox browsers ? Is that connected with Javascript ?